# Parsing text file in python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have html-file. I have to replace all text between this: [%anytext%]. As I understand, it's very easy to do with BeautifulSoup for parsing hmtl. But what is regular expression and how to remove&write back text data?

---

Okay, here is the sample file:

```
<html>
  [t1] [t2] ... [tood] ... [sadsada]
  Sample text [i8]
  [d9]
</html>
```

Python script must work with all strings and replace [%] -> some another string, for example:

```
<html>
  * * ... * ... *
  Sample text *
  *
</html>
```

---

What I did:

```
import re
import codecs

fullData = ''
for line in codecs.open(u'test.txt', encoding='utf-8'):
    line = re.sub("\[.*?\]", '*', line)
    fullData += line

print fullData
```

This code does exactly I described in sample. Thanks all.

Comment: It would be easier if you show us an exaple with input and expected output, simple Python code you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex does the trick if you are needing to replace any text between "[%" and "%]".

The code would look something like this:

```
import re


newstring = re.sub("\[%.*?%\]",newtext,oldstring)
```

The regex used here is lazy so it would match everything between an occurrence of "[%" and the next occurrence of "%]". You could make it greedy by removing the question mark. This would match everything between the first occurrence of of "[%" and the last occurrence of "%]"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to parse a generic textfile, looking for that marker to replace it -- the fact that other text outside the marker is HTML, at least from the way you phrased your task, does not seem to matter.

If so, and what you want is to replace every occurrence of `[%anytext%]` with `loremipsum`, then a simple:

```
thenew = theold.replace('[%anytext%]', 'loremipsum')
```

will serve, if `theold` is the original string containing the file's text -- now `thenew` is a new string with all occurrences of that marker replaced - no need for regex, BS or anything else.

If your task is very different from this, pls edit your Question to explain it in more detail!-)

Comment: the task came from a prior answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580343/removing-template-string-from-html-file-with-javascript

Comment: Yeah, JavaScript is not compatible with another needing, so we chose python for this.